# View cannot resolve action

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, razor, razor-pages

I was configuring CRUD in my project and I ran into a problem. View does not see the method from the controller. I used the main view with partial views.
Main view code:

```
<div class="container col-md-10 m-auto" style="width: auto;">
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-with-image" onclick="sendObjectType('Star')">
                <div class="div-with-image" style="background-image: url('../Graphics/StaticImages/star.png');"></div>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-with-image" onclick="sendObjectType('Planet')">
                <div class="div-with-image" style="background-image: url('../Graphics/StaticImages/planet.png');"></div>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-with-image" onclick="sendObjectType('Moon')">
                <div class="div-with-image" style="background-image: url('../Graphics/StaticImages/moon.png');"></div>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="partialContainer">
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function sendObjectType(objectType) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Encyclopedia/Create",
            data: { objectType: objectType },
            success: function (partialView) {
                $("#partialContainer").html(partialView);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Code for partial view:

```
@model SolarSystemEncyclopedia.Models.Planet

<div style="margin-top: 2%; margin-bottom: 2%;">
    <div class="container-fluid col-md-10 m-auto">
        <div class="row container-fluid d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-6 blue-div">
                <h1>Create planet</h1>
                <form asp-controller="Encyclopedia" asp-action="CreatePartial" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    <div class="form-group mb-3">
                        <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control main-inputs" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group mb-3">
                        <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Description" class="form-control main-inputs" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group mb-3">
                        <input type="submit" value="CreateMain" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

In the controller I have the following methods:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
{
    return View();
}



[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(string objectType)
{
    switch (objectType)
    {
        case "Star":
            return PartialView("_CreateStarPartial");
        case "Planet":
            return PartialView("_CreatePlanetPartial");
        case "Moon":
            return PartialView("_CreateMoonPartial");
        default:
            return BadRequest();
    }
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreatePartial<T>(T obj) where T : CosmicObject
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid == true)
    {
        if (obj is Planet planet)
        {
            var star = _context.Star.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == planet.MainStarId);
            planet.MainStar = star;
            planet.Density = Double.Parse(planet.StringDensity);
        }

        if (obj.MainImage != null)
        {
            string uploadsFolder = Path.Combine(_appEnvironment.WebRootPath, "Graphics", "ObjectImages", obj.Name);
            string uniqueFileName = obj.Name + "MainImage.jpg";
            string filePath = Path.Combine(uploadsFolder, uniqueFileName);

            if (!Directory.Exists(uploadsFolder))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(uploadsFolder);
            }

            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await obj.MainImage.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
            }

        }
        _context.Add(obj);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    return View(obj);
}
```

The first method opens the main view, the second opens the partial view, and the third should open after the form is submitted.

I changed the names of the methods, tried adding different tags to the form in the view, but nothing worked. The form indicates that the post method should be called, but even when the post method and the get method have the same names, the get method is called for some reason.
I searched the internet and found that it might be related to ajax, but I couldn't find a way to fix it.

Comment: How are your models defined?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your `AJAX` call is incomplete. Also why is the `Create` GET method `async` ? You can refer to the below changes to your code that will hopefully solve your problem:

Change your `AJAX` call to:

```
<script>
    function sendObjectType(objectType) {
        var param = { objectType: objectType};
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("Create", "Encyclopedia")',
            data: { "json": JSON.stringify(param)},
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (partialView) {
                $("#partialContainer").html(partialView);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

And your `Controller` methods will look like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}


[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(string json)
{
    var jsondata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
    string objectType = Convert.ToString(jsondata["objectType"]);
    switch (objectType)
    {
        case "Star":
            return PartialView("_CreateStarPartial");
        case "Planet":
            return PartialView("_CreatePlanetPartial");
        case "Moon":
            return PartialView("_CreateMoonPartial");
        default:
            return BadRequest();
    }
}
```

Comment: I found the cause of the error, everything is related to the use of generics in the CreatePartial method. My idea was to be able to create objects of different types using the same method, but I haven't figured out how to fix that. So I created a separate Create method for each object type. I'm not sure if this is the right way to solve the problem, but I haven't found another one. I have also included your code in the view, thanks for your help.